# How to validate nested component forms?

Tags: angular

Is it possile to validate the nested components form, if I have the next code?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <form novalidate #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="validateForm(form)">
    ...
    </form>
    
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
});
export class AppParentComponent {
  constructor() {}
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <form novalidate>
      <input type="text" required maxlength="80" />
    </form>
  `
});
export class AppChildComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

In the `<router-outlet>` I have the child component. So the idea is to validate the parent component, dependent on the fields filled in the childComponent.

Hope you help!)

Comment: You shouldn't be nesting forms in the first place.

Comment: @JamieBarker, what do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms